# Queryset in one to many relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to get a `Json` of elements with their related elements

I had two tables, `Service` and `Room`. One service have many rooms. I would like to get the service where have `room_id = x`.

Models

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Service'

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Room'
```

Serializer

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_set = RoomSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Service
       fields = ('name','room_set')
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room        
        fields = '__all__'
```

View

```
queryset = Service.objects.filter(room__id=1)
serializer = ServiceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

I expect a Json like this:

```
{
     "name": "Hotel1",
     "room_set": [
     {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Room1"
      },
```

But I get this:

```
 {
     "name": "Hotel1",
     "room_set": [
     {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Room1",
      },
      {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Room2",
      },
      {
             "id": 3,
             "name": "Room3",
      }
  }
```

Is it possible to get a json like the one I'm expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the set by adding a *custom* [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) with a filtered queryset, like:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = Service.objects.filter(
    room__id=1
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('room_set', queryset=Room.objects.filter(id=1), to_attr='room_set1')
)
serializer = ServiceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

and let the `Serializer` parse the new related manager:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_set = RoomSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='room_set1')
    class Meta:
       model = Service
       fields = ('name','room_set1')
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room        
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, but this solution returns me an error: TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use room_set.set() instead. I have changed to_attr='room_set' for to_attr='room_set.set()' and the result is the same that I got at the begining, not the result I am expecting.

Comment: @user1818759: what if you rename the `to_attr` to `room_set1`.

Comment: Yes, now it works, but in ServiceSerializer, in fields must be 'room_set' instead 'room_set1'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the room id via the serializer context and filter accordingly inside a [SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
       model = Service
       fields = ('name','rooms')

    get_rooms(self,service):
       room_id = self.get_context('room')
       if room_id:
         queryset = service.rooms_set.filter(id=room_id)
         return RoomSerializer(queryset,many=True).data
       return RoomSerializer(service.rooms_set.all(),many=True).data

serializer = ServiceSerializer(queryset, many=True,context={'room':1})
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

This's how to do it via the serializer and it's highly customizable , [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307890/4784913)'s answer is brief enough , but it also requires two queries the same as of mine.